# Is there any sample Production ready web app that uses GWT2.2 MVP

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I'm looking for real time production ready j2ee web app that uses GWT 2.1+ and MVP . Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks,
Kruthika

Answer (score 0):

The application framework introduced with GWT 2.1 is quite well documented. In the tutorial a sample project is used:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html
The new activities and places stuff was only just introduced with GWT 2.2. I found a quite cool MVP sample app in the a blog post right here:
http://www.bright-creations.com/blog/gwt-2-1-mvp-client-factory-example/
I don't think that there are any other exmples yet...